# Creating Gradle test task with multiple categories such that it only selects tests where all categories are applied

Tags: java, testing, gradle, junit

I am trying to create a Gradle test task which will only run tests that is annotated with more than one Junit test category. So basically an AND condition on test categories instead of the OR used by default by Gradle when selecting tests for inclusion.

For example, I have two test categories main & debug, I want to create a task that will only pick up tests which are annotated with both categories. If one of the category is not present, then should not get picked up.

The main reason I want to do this because I have a few main test categories and its possible that I want to use debug on more than one main category at the same time (but not run them together) and I want the task to not pick up the test that does not qualify that main category because the setup needed for them are different.

I hope I am clear on my requirement :)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Johnson